# Question on completeness of graphs in Cayley's Formula

Tags: graph-theory, trees

In my textbook, Cayley's Formula is presented as follows:

> There are $n^{n-2}$ distinct labeled trees of order $n$.

However, this statement says nothing about whether or not this formula applies to complete graphs only, which it does. I'm certain that the textbook isn't incorrect, so why is it that the theorem is presented in this way? What am I missing here?

Comment: The theorem states that among graphs with $n$ vertices, there are $n^{n-2}$ isomorphism classes of trees. A tree can only be a complete graph when $n=1$ or $n=2$ so your question doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of the theorem that applies to  complete graphs only is

> There are are $n^{n-2}$ spanning trees of the complete graph on $n$ vertices.

Indeed, if you replace the complete graph with any other graph, the number will change.

But the version of the theorem that states

> There are $n^{n-2}$ labeled trees on $n$ vertices.

isn't making a claim about spanning trees at all. It is simply counting connected, acyclic graphs on a fixed vertex set of size $n$.

Of course, it's not hard to see that the two statements are equivalent: any spanning tree of $K_n$ has $n$ vertices, and any tree on $n$ vertices is a spanning tree of $K_n$.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I understand the equivalency between a tree on $n$ vertices and a spanning tree of $K_n$ having $n$ vertices. However, I'm still confused about what you mean when you say "the number will change." If, as you state, $n^{n-2}$ applies to complete graphs only, why was the theorem stated without this qualification in the text?

Comment: My point is that the theorem is stated without qualification because the theorem is not making a claim about spanning trees to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this works for counting spanning subtrees of $K_n$.

If you want to count spanning subtrees of any graph $G$ you can use Kirchoffs theorem, Cayleys theorem is a particular case as the laplacian of $K_n$ has spectra $[n-1]^{n-1},[0]^1$